# lineTo() Not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

`lineTo()` function is not working for me, why? Here is the code.

```
<canvas id="sid" height="1000px" width="1000px"> </canvas>
<script>
    var can = document.querySelector('#sid');

    var a = can.getContext('2d');

    a.beginPath();
    a.moveTo(0, 0);
    a.lineTo(140, 140);
    a.lineTo(160, 160);

</script>
```

Comment: What are you seeing or not seeing? Have you checked that your canvas has a width and height? Also you need to stroke() at the end.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to call the [`stroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) function. It would be very helpful for you to check out the documentation, where it's explained in a more clear way.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke):

> The **`CanvasRenderingContext2D.stroke()`** method of the Canvas 2D API strokes the current or given path with the current stroke style using the non-zero winding rule.

```html
<canvas id="sid" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>   
<script>
  var can = document.querySelector('#sid');

  var a = can.getContext('2d');

  a.beginPath();
  a.moveTo(0, 0);
  a.lineTo(140, 140);
  a.lineTo(160, 160);
  // After this you need to run the stroke command to get the line.
  a.stroke();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not stroking the line after you've defined it. Just add the `stroke()` method.

```
<canvas id="sid" height="1000px" width="1000px">       </canvas>   
<script>
var can = document.querySelector('#sid');
var a = can.getContext('2d');
a.beginPath();
a.moveTo(0, 0);
a.lineTo(140, 140);
a.lineTo(160, 160);
a.stroke();  // This line is the import one being omitted.
a.closePath(); // You should close your path also. Not absolutely necessary in this case, given that stroke() will do this for you.
</script>
```

Comment: You do not need the `ctx.closePath()` call. See my comment to Praveen's answer above.

Comment: Yeah, it's not absolutely necessary in this instance, but it's worthwhile noting it to the OP for their future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
   <canvas id="sid" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>   
   <script>
        var can = document.getElementById("sid");
        var a = can.getContext('2d');
        a.beginPath();
        a.lineWidth = "5";
        a.strokeStyle = "green";
        a.moveTo(0,0);
        a.lineTo(140,140);
        a.lineTo(160,160);
       a.stroke();
   </script>      
</body>
</html>
```